# Trying to extract child node values from xml in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AdminDirectorUsers>
    <Users>
        <User>
            <UserName>PC1</UserName>
            <Installation>
                <Products>
                    <Product>
                        <ProductID>Product1</ProductID>
                        <Selected>Yes</Selected>
                    </Product>
                    <Product>
                        <ProductID>Product2</ProductID>
                        <Selected>No</Selected>
                    </Product>
                    <Product>
                        <ProductID>Product3</ProductID>
                        <Selected>No</Selected>
                    </Product>
                    <Product>
                        <ProductID>Product4</ProductID>
                        <Selected>Yes</Selected>                        
                    </Product>
                </Products>
            </Installation>
        </User>
        <User>
            <UserName>PC2</UserName>
            <Installation>
                <Products>
                    <Product>
                        <ProductID>Product1</ProductID>
                        <Selected>Yes</Selected>
                    </Product>
                    <Product>
                        <ProductID>Product2</ProductID>
                        <Selected>Yes</Selected>
                    </Product>
                    <Product>
                        <ProductID>Product3</ProductID>
                        <Selected>No</Selected>
                    </Product>
                    <Product>
                        <ProductID>Product4</ProductID>
                        <Selected>Yes</Selected>                        
                    </Product>
                </Products>
            </Installation>
        </User>
    </Users>
</AdminDirectorUsers>
```

I would like to loop through and extract a list of each **UserName** with all **ProductID**s that has a sibling node **Selected** with a value of **Yes**, while ignoring the values of **No**.

```
$path = 'C:\Temp\test.xml'
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($Path)
$UserNode = $xml.SelectNodes('//User')
$ProductNode = $xml.SelectNodes('//Product')

foreach ($PC in $usernode)
{
  $PC.username
  foreach($Node in $ProductNode){
    # Test if selected == 'yes'
    if($Node.Selected -eq 'yes') {
      $Node.ProductID
    }
  }
}
```

My output is:

```
PC1
Product1
Product4
Product1
Product2
Product4
PC2
Product1
Product4
Product1
Product2
Product4
```

...but I'm looking for:

```
PC1
Product1
Product4
PC2
Product1
Product2
Product4
```

I've tried many ways to do this but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second XPath expression used for the `Product`/`ProductID` to only get the *descendants* of a specific `<User>` element, by anchoring against `.` (the "current node"):

```
# Enumerate each `<User>` element
$xml |Select-Xml '//User' |%{
  # Grab the exact username value
  $username = $_.Node.UserName

  # Then enumerate all descendant `<ProductID>` nodes who has a sibling `<Selected>Yes</Selected>` and attach username
  $_.Node |Select-Xml './/ProductID[../Selected[. = "Yes"]]' |Select -Expand Node |Select @{Name='Username';Expression={$username}},InnerText
}
```

(I'm using `Select-Xml` here but this works the same with the `SelectNodes()` method)

Comment: This was driving my crazy! Thank you, I could not figure out how to anchor it to get only the descendants.

Comment: @strayletters You're most welcome! Note that you can describe the relative position in the path the same way you would with the file system (`.` describes "this node", `..` describes the immediate parent)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
Clear-Host
[XML]$Data = Get-Content 'C:\temp\test.xml'
[array]$UsersData = $Data.AdminDirectorUsers.Users.User
foreach($PC in $UsersData) {
    $PC.username
    foreach($Node in $PC.Installation.Products.Product){
        if($Node.Selected -eq 'Yes') {
            $Node.ProductID
        }
    }
}
```

My result with your xml file is

```
PC1
Product1
Product4
PC2
Product1
Product2
Product4
```

Comment: This works great too! That was the output I was asking for. I never thought of using an array like that. Handy to keep in my back pocket.